# Иерархия классов

Tags: java

подскажите пожалуйста какая будет иерархия наследования для следующих классов:
деталь, механизм, изделие, узел.

Мне не нужен код, просто иерархия наследования этих классов в 2 словах.
Спасибо!

Comment: Никакого наследования, только композиция.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На самом деле вы смотрите не много не так.
Наследование это производная от класса, т.е. то что получится после изменения базового.

Так вот начнем с определений.

**Деталь** - изготовленное, изготавливаемое или же подлежащее изготовлению изделие, являющееся частью изделия, машины или же какой-либо технической конструкции, изготавливаемое из однородного по структуре и свойствам материала без применения при этом каких-либо сборочных операций.

**Механизм** - внутреннее устройство машины, прибора, аппарата, приводящее их в действие. Например: Часовой механизм, механизм насоса. переносное значение механизм — система, устройство, определяющие порядок какого-нибудь вида деятельности, процесса.

**Изделие** - предмет, созданный в ходе производственного процесса

**Узел** - изделие, составные части которого (детали) подверглись соединению между собой сборочными операциями на предприятии-изготовителе. Узел, в зависимости от конструкции, может состоять из отдельных деталей или узлов и деталей. Технологическая особенность узла — возможность его сборки независимо от других частей изделия.

деталь -> узел -> механизм -> изделие

Как видно ни одно не может быть наследником другого так как каждый состоит и элементов.

Comment: Я так же и думал, просто это задание в универе на лабораторную дали, и я решил спросить у других, может я что-то не доганяю) Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @Vlad Если ответ помог то галочка под стремлками